# Can't recover Checkbox state with onChange method

Tags: reactjs, checkbox

I'm working with reactjs, trying to say that when the state of the checkbox changes I want to do this or that.

The issue is, I can't recover the checkbox state.

Here is my checkbox component from ***checkbox.jsx***:

```
const Checkbox = ({ input, label, disabled }) => (
    <div>
        <Input
            {...input}
            id={input.name}
            checked={input.value}
            type="checkbox"
            disabled={disabled}
        />
        <Label htmlFor={input.name}>{label}</Label>
    </div>
)
```

Here is my code for rendering the checkbox in ***form.jsx***:

```
  <div className="col-md-3">
    <Field 
      name="checkboxName"
      type="checkbox"
      component={Checkbox}
      label="checkbox name"
      onChange={changeCheckboxValue(Checkbox.state.value)}
    />
   </div>
```

my code for changeCheckboxValue in ***Checkbox.jsx*** (just printing the value passed in parameter):

```
export const changeCheckboxValue = (value) => {
    console.log(value)
}
```

I precise that the form is not a class but a const.

I'm not a reactjs developer and struggle quite a lot with understanding where this error comes from.

UPDATE:

Thanks to Davo Mkrtchyan, I've updated my code as follow

I added those lines to ***checkbox.jsx***

```
export const [count, setCount] = useState(false)
export const isChecked = () => true === count
```

And changed checkbox field rendering in ***form.jsx*** to :

```
<div className="col-md-3">
  <Field
    name="checkboxname"
    type="checkbox"
    component={Checkbox}
    label="Travailleur handicapé"
    onClick={() => setCount(!count)}
  />
</div>
```

Now I got the following error :

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

I understand it might be due to useState (if I delete the line containing it I no longer have this error) my question would be, why ?

If anyone has any hints for me I'd appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: What does your `Field` component look like?

Comment: Can you please create codesandbox example?

Answer (score 0):

So, if you want to use your Input's state, you need to use useState() hook, something like this:

```
export const CheckBoxComponent = (props) => {

  const [check,setChecked] = useState(false);

  const onChange = () => {
    setChecked(!check)
  };

  const handlerFunction = () =>{
   if(checked){
     //do stuff 
   } else {
    // do other stuff
  };
}

  return (
   <Input
     {...input}
     id={input.name}
     checked={check}  // <----- check is current state
     type="checkbox"
     onChange={onChange} // <----- onChange will update current state
     disabled={disabled}
   />)
}
```

You can look at docs of useState [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

I hope this helps, if no, please share codesanbox, or repl, so we can investigate your case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply it helped me advance! I updated my issue because I still have issues I don't quite understand.

Comment: You don't understand how useState works, so I updated my answer. You should use useState inside your component,

Comment: Ok, I see. Now I got another problem being that my checkbox imported as <Field> in form.jsx don't recognize the onChange function because it is declared in Checkbox.jsx file. I've tried importing the componant like this : <Checkbox /> (instead of <Field ...> but it did not work. Do you have hints about this ?

Comment: Please upload your code to codesandbox, or codepen so we can see the whole project